# Stored procedure in SQL Server is inserting the same data multiple times

Tags: sql-server

I am busy coding a stored procedure, however when I run the procedure, it inserts the same data multiple times, whereas I only want it to insert once. How do I stop this from happening?

My SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployeeRecord
     (@EMP_NUM VARCHAR(3),  
      @Emp_LNAME VARCHAR(200), 
      @Emp_FNAME VARCHAR(200),  
      @EMP_INITIAL VARCHAR(50), 
      @EMP_HIREDATE DATETIME,  
      @JOB_CODE VARCHAR(20),  
      @EMP_YEARS INT)  
AS  
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, Emp_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE, EMP_YEARS)    
    VALUES (@emp_num, @Emp_LNAME, @Emp_FNAME, @EMP_INITIAL, @EMP_HIREDATE, @JOB_CODE, @EMP_YEARS)  
END

EXEC InsertEmployeerecord   
        @emp_num = '119',  
        @Emp_LNAME = 'Lucas',  
        @Emp_FNAME = 'Khoza',   
        @EMP_INITIAL = 'L',   
        @EMP_HIREDATE = '2019-02-02',  
        @JOB_CODE = '526',   
        @EMP_YEARS = '2';
```

Here is what happens:

[image]

Comment: Your procedure looks fine. Are you absolutely sure that you have only run it once? try running `delete from employee where emp_num = 119` and then try the exec again.

Comment: @paul Tried it, and it still does it, it looks like it is inserting 32 times for some odd reason

Comment: make sure that you haven't included the `exec` statement in your stored procedure definition - if you ran your snippet as is, you would need a 'GO' between the `create` and the `exec`

Comment: Is there any `TRIGGER` on your table?

Comment: @paul tried that too, still does the same even with the `GO`

Comment: @Sami No there isnt

Comment: 32 times is the default maximum nesting limit, so I think somehow your procedure is calling itself.

Comment: There is two (2) possible things, you  run your `SP` multiple times, or there is a `TRIGGER` insert the data. except those I don't think `SQL Server` can do that.

Comment: @Sami I highlight it and i press the run query button once and it does this, I have ran the same code on a friends computer and it does the same thing, so could it be, i configured something wrong?

Comment: @DigitalHack Sorry, I can't answer according to a guess.

Comment: @Sami I change `@emp_num`to something else and it added it only once, i guess something wrong with 119 lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was clicking the execute button without highlighting just the

```
    CREATE Procedure InsertEmployeerecord
 (  @EMP_NUM varchar (3),  
 @Emp_LNAME Varchar(200), 
  @Emp_FNAME  Varchar(200),  
  @EMP_INITIAL    Varchar(50), 
   @EMP_HIREDATE datetime ,  
   @JOB_CODE varchar(20),  
   @EMP_YEARS int  )  



   As  
   Begin    
   Insert into  EMPLOYEE(EMP_NUM,EMP_LNAME, Emp_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE,JOB_CODE, EMP_YEARS)    
   Values (@emp_num, @Emp_LNAME, @Emp_FNAME,@EMP_INITIAL,@EMP_HIREDATE,@JOB_CODE,@EMP_YEARS)  
   End
```

Instead i ran the entire code:

```
        CREATE Procedure InsertEmployeerecord
 (  @EMP_NUM varchar (3),  
 @Emp_LNAME Varchar(200), 
  @Emp_FNAME  Varchar(200),  
  @EMP_INITIAL    Varchar(50), 
   @EMP_HIREDATE datetime ,  
   @JOB_CODE varchar(20),  
   @EMP_YEARS int  )  
   As  
   Begin    
   Insert into  EMPLOYEE(EMP_NUM,EMP_LNAME, Emp_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE,JOB_CODE, EMP_YEARS)    
   Values (@emp_num, @Emp_LNAME, @Emp_FNAME,@EMP_INITIAL,@EMP_HIREDATE,@JOB_CODE,@EMP_YEARS)  
   End 


EXEC InsertEmployeerecord   
@emp_num = '119',  
 @Emp_LNAME = 'Lucas',  
  @Emp_FNAME = 'Khoza',   
  @EMP_INITIAL = 'L',   
  @EMP_HIREDATE = '2019-02-02',  
   @JOB_CODE = '526',   
   @EMP_YEARS = '2';
```

Which somehow multiplied itself, so the solution would be to first run the `CREATE Procedure InsertEmployeerecord` and after that run the `EXEC InsertEmployeerecord` separately.

Comment: or have a `GO` between the `CREATE` and the `EXEC`